# Non italicized text in tufte-handout

Tags: tufte, italic, handout

I want to have a part of tufte-handout title non-italicized. Is there a way I can force just a part of the title to be written in roman not italics?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,nofonts,nols,justified]{tufte-handout}
\renewcommand{\smallcaps}[1]{\emph{\textsc #1}}

\title{Title non italicized bit}
\author{Author}
\date{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@footnotetext[2][0pt]{%
\@noftnotefalse\setcounter{fnx}{0}% added by gb4e
\marginpar{%
\hbox{}\vspace*{#1}%
\def\baselinestretch {\setspace@singlespace}%
\reset@font\footnotesize%
\@tufte@margin@par% use parindent and parskip settings for marginal text
\vspace*{-1\baselineskip}\noindent%
\protected@edef\@currentlabel{%
   \csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark%
 }%
 \color@begingroup%
   \@makefntext{%
    }%
  \color@endgroup%
 }%
\@noftnotetrue% added by g4be
}%
 \makeatother % End of Tufte-LaTeX-related code.

\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{\begingroup%
 \addtolength{\parsep}{1ex}
 \renewcommand\thefootnote\relax\footnote{#1}%
\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
\endgroup%
}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `{\upshape non italicized bit}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,nofonts,nols,justified]{tufte-handout} 
\title{Title {\upshape non italicized bit}}
\author{Author}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\rm` isn't defined in LaTeX; it's a "plain" command.  Instead, use its LaTeX equivalent: `\rmfamily`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks. I updated it to `\upshape`.

Comment: Is there also a way to use an equivalent of \texsc{non italicized} to generate small caps?

Comment: @bozidarka - Give `\scshape` a try.